# Blockarray Column Distance

Tags: tables

Is there a setting for horizontal space in blockarray?
I need the columns to be closer together in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
    
\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccccccccccccccc}
  & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 & c_6 & c_7 & c_8 & c_9 & c_{10} & c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14} & c_{15} \\
  \begin{block}{c ccccccccccccccc }
  r_1    & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &     \\ 
  r_2    &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &     \\
  r_3    &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &     \\
  r_4    &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &     \\
  r_5    &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &     \\
  r_6    &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &     \\
  r_7    &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &     \\
  r_8    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  & | &     \\
  r_9    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  & |    \\
  r_{10} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  & |    \\
  r_{11} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  & |    \\
  r_{12} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  & |    \\
\end{blockarray}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The body of the array should more look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this like you want?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{blkarray}
    \makeatletter
    \AtBeginDocument{\BA@colsep=3pt}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \[
    \begin{blockarray}{*{16}{c}}
      & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 & c_6 & c_7 & c_8 & c_9 & c_{10} & c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14} & c_{15} \\
      \begin{block}{c ccccccccccccccc }
      r_1 & | & & & & & & & & & & & & | & & \\
      r_2 & & | & & & & & & & & & & & | & & \\
      r_3 & & & | & & & & & & & & & & | & & \\
      r_4 & & & & | & & & & & & & & & | & & \\
      r_5 & & & & & | & & & & & & & & & | & \\
      r_6 & & & & & & | & & & & & & & & | & \\
      r_7 & & & & & & & | & & & & & & & | & \\
      r_8 & & & & & & & & | & & & & & & | & \\
      r_9 & & & & & & & & & | & & & & & & | \\
      r_{10} & & & & & & & & & & | & & & & & | \\
      r_{11} & & & & & & & & & & & | & & & & | \\
      r_{12} & & & & & & & & & & & & | & & & | \\
    \end{blockarray}
     \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes @Bernard, that does the job, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!

Answer (score 2):

You *don't* need `blkarray`, unless you want to add delimiters. In this case, prefer the more modern and more powerful `nicematrix` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
\[
\begin{array}{@{} l *{15}{c} @{}}
  & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 & c_6 & c_7 & c_8 & c_9 &
  c_{10} & c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14} & c_{15} \\
  r_1    & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &     \\ 
  r_2    &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &     \\
  r_3    &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &     \\
  r_4    &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &     \\
  r_5    &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &     \\
  r_6    &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &     \\
  r_7    &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &     \\
  r_8    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  & | &     \\
  r_9    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  & |    \\
  r_{10} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  & |    \\
  r_{11} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  & |    \\
  r_{12} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  & |    \\
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{bNiceArray}{*{15}{c}}[first-row,first-col]
  & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 & c_6 & c_7 & c_8 & c_9 &
  c_{10} & c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14} & c_{15} \\
  r_1    & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &     \\ 
  r_2    &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &     \\
  r_3    &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &     \\
  r_4    &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &     \\
  r_5    &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &     \\
  r_6    &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &     \\
  r_7    &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &     \\
  r_8    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  & | &     \\
  r_9    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  &  & |    \\
  r_{10} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  &  & |    \\
  r_{11} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  &  & |    \\
  r_{12} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & | &  &  & |    \\
\end{bNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg, this is valuable as well.